# Kio estas la diferenco inter "honoro" kaj "omaĝo"?

Tags: word-difference

Bonvolu klarigi al mi kiuj frazoj ĝustas:

- Estas granda honoro por mi ke vi estas ĉi tie
- Estas granda omaĝo por mi ke vi estas ĉi tie

Kaj bonvolu doni al mi kelkajn ekzemplojn kun la ĝusta uzado de ambaŭ vortoj.

Comment: Bv. ŝanĝi en via demando „homaĝo”  (la aĝo de homo) al „omaĝo”.

Comment: @PaŭlPeeraerts dankon, mi faris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Estas granda omaĝo por mi ke vi estas ĉi tie.

Tia frazo ne havas sencon. Oni omaĝas al iu pro liaj meritoj, valoro. Jen kelkaj ekzemploj:

- mallonga omaĝo al la mortintaj gesamideanoj
- nia omaĝo al karmemora Nikolai Lozgaĉev
- li omaĝis al mi per dediĉo en sia libro
- okazis hieraŭ diskreta omaĝo al la viktimoj de la akcidento

Cetere, ekzemplofrazojn vi povas facile trovi en tekstaro.com